# Affect absolute div's height based on parent's other content

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I see lots of questions about how to have an absolutely positioned child affect the parent div's height, but I'm not sure how to do the opposite. I have an absolutely positioned child, and I want its height to be affected by the other content's of its parent.

HTML:

```
<div class="timeline">

  <div class="line"></div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="date">January 1, 2017</h1>
    <h1 class="info">Info</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.timeline {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    border: thick orange solid;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #a2ff94;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.item {
    width: 50%;
    border: thin red solid;
}
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/t2ory9j4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change .timeline to

```
.timeline {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    border: thick orange solid;
    position: relative;
}
```

and .line to

```
.line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #a2ff94;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```